# PHP / SQL: Multiple delete unsucessful

Tags: php, sql

currently I have created a system that can perform multiple delete actions for a list of data rows that fetch from a SQL database and display at `dashboard_engineer.php`. Each data row contains a delete button. Each row also has a checkbox that enables the user to delete selected data rows. At the bottom of the data rows, there's a button to delete all the selected data rows.

My problem is on multiple delete, lets say, if I select two data rows, (id 4 and 5) it will only delete one ID.

Below is my code

**dashboard_engineer2.php**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_REQUEST['from'], $_REQUEST['to'], $_REQUEST['team'])){

    $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
    $to   = $_REQUEST['to'];
    $team = $_REQUEST['team'];

    $result = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid 
    WHERE ot_report.status = 'yes' AND ot_users.team_id = :team AND report_date BETWEEN :from 
    AND :to ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC";

    $sql = $conn->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $sql->bindParam(':team', $team);
    $sql->bindParam(':from', $from);
    $sql->bindParam(':to', $to,);
    $sql -> execute(); 

    if($sql->rowCount() > 0){

    echo'

        <table class = "table-bordered" width = "100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th width = "10%"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAl"> All</th>
        <th width = "3%">id</th>
        <th width = "15%">Date</th>
        <th width = "25%">Supervisor</th>
        <th width = "30%">Task Name</th>
        <th width = "10%">Status</th>
        <th colspan = "2" width = "7%">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

            $i=0;

            while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $status=$row['report_status'];

            if($status=="Pending"){
                $color="color:blue";
            }
            else {
                $color="color:green";
            }

            $report_id = $row["report_id"];

            echo'<tr>';
                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" name="check[]" value="'.$report_id.'"></td>';
                echo '<td>'.$report_id.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row['report_date'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["fullname"].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$row["task_name"].'</td>';
                echo '<td align="center" style='.$color.'><strong>'.$status.'</strong></td>';

                echo '<td align="center">';
                    echo '<form action = "view_task/view_task.php" method = "post" target="_blank">';
                        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "report_id" value = "'.$report_id.'">';
                        echo '<button type = "submit" class="btn-primary">View</button>';
                    echo '</form>';
                echo '</td>';

                echo '<td align="center">';
                    echo "<form action = 'remove2.php' method = 'post' onClick=\"return confirm('Do you want to remove this reports?')\">";
                        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "from" value = "'.$from.'">';
                        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "to" value = "'.$to.'">';
                        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "team" value = "'.$team.'">';
                        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "report_id" value = "'.$report_id.'">';
                        echo '<button type = "submit" class="btn-danger">Remove</button>';
                    echo '</form>';
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $i++;

            }

            echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>';
                    echo "<form action = 'delete_selected.php' method = 'post'>";
                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="checkItem" name="check[]" value="'.$report_id.'">';
                        echo '<button type="submit" class="btn-danger btn-sm">DELETE</button>';
                    echo '</form>';  
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

        }

    } 

?>
```

**delete_selected.php**

```
<?php

    include("../../../config/configPDO.php");
    include("../../../config/check.php");


    $checkbox = $_POST['check'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
        $report_id = $checkbox[$i];

        $sql = "UPDATE ot_report SET status = 'no' WHERE report_id=:report_id";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));

        header("Location: dashboard_engineer.php");

    }

?>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Its better if you can isolate the problem. Make sure your form submit more than 1 value when multiple checked

Comment: you cannot have multiple IDs the same such as `checkItem`

Comment: you looped in outside form...
in your delete form it set only the **last value**...

Comment: @RamRaider can you give the answer in code?

Comment: @AntonyJack can you edit my code above?

Comment: the problem is only delete the last value... am I correct...???

Comment: @AnthonyJack it only delete the first id in database. if I select 4 and 5, it will delete id no 1. next if I delete 5 and 6, it will delete only id no 2

Comment: yes... you passed **check** by hidden box so it's stopped in first loop and delete in the query...

Comment: @AnthonyJack, can you edit the code above? please

Comment: why are you using multiple forms... you need to keep the checkbox inside the form only...

so you must need to create form above the loop where start...

Comment: If you are happy to use some basic javascript then I believe I could point you in the right direction

Comment: @RamRaider if you have the solution, just share the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - the following is based upon the question's code but in order to build a working demo it has been generalised. The important thing here is the use of Javascript to maintain the list of IDs selected ( either by clicking the `select-all` checkbox or by clicking individual checkboxes. Please ignore the content generated in the form - the dates are spurious and meaningless to this example.

You could copy this and create a test page which should run OK - the PHP that generates the pseudo SQL is simply to display the statements that would be executed and not how it should be executed ( should be as per question, `prepared statement` )

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( isset( $_POST['ids'] ) ){
            $items=explode( ',', $_POST['ids'][0] );

            foreach($items as $id){
                $sql=sprintf('UPDATE ot_report SET status="no" WHERE report_id=%d',$id);
                echo $sql . '<br />';
            }
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <?php

                for( $i=1; $i <= 10; $i++ ){
                    /* example data for dates... */
                    $hrs=mt_rand(1,24);
                    $mins=mt_rand(0,60);
                    $secs=mt_rand(0,60);

                    $month=mt_rand(1,12);
                    $day=mt_rand(1,28);
                    $year=mt_rand(2000,2020);

                    $from=date('y-m-d',mktime($hrs,$mins,$secs,$month,$day,$year));
                    $to=date('y-m-d',mktime($hrs+3,$mins+20,$secs,$month,$day,$year));

                    printf('
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="%1$d" /></td>
                        <td>Some data %1$d</td>
                        <td>
                            <form method="post">
                                <input type="hidden" name="from" value="%2$s" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="to" value="%3$s" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="%1$d" />
                                <input type="submit" />
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>', $i, $from, $to );
                }

            ?>
        </table>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='selectall' value='Select-All' />
            <input type='hidden' name='ids[]' />
            <input type='button' name='sub-delete' value='Update selected' />
        </form>
        <script>
            let ids=document.querySelector('input[type="hidden"][name="ids[]"]');
            let tmp=[];

            document.querySelector('[name="selectall"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
                let col=document.querySelectorAll('[name="check[]"]');
                col.forEach(chk=>{
                    chk.checked=this.checked;
                    if( this.checked )tmp.push(chk.value)
                    else tmp.splice(tmp.indexOf(chk.value),1)
                });
            });

            document.querySelectorAll('[name="check[]"]').forEach( chk=>{
                chk.addEventListener('change',function(e){
                    if( this.checked )tmp.push(this.value)
                    else tmp.splice( tmp.indexOf(this.value),1);
                });
            });

            document.querySelector('[name="sub-delete"]').addEventListener('click',function(e){
                ids.value=tmp.join(',')
                this.parentNode.submit()
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Will generate something akin to:

```
UPDATE ot_report SET status="no" WHERE report_id=10
UPDATE ot_report SET status="no" WHERE report_id=8
UPDATE ot_report SET status="no" WHERE report_id=6
UPDATE ot_report SET status="no" WHERE report_id=4
```

Quickly trying to adapt this example with your code :

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['from'], $_REQUEST['to'], $_REQUEST['team'])){
        $from=$_REQUEST['from'];
        $to  =$_REQUEST['to'];
        $team=$_REQUEST['team'];

        $result='';
        $query="SELECT * FROM ot_report 
                LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid=ot_users.badgeid 
                WHERE ot_report.status='yes' AND ot_users.team_id=:team AND report_date BETWEEN :from AND :to 
                ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC";

        $sql=$conn->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
        $sql->bindParam(':team', $team);
        $sql->bindParam(':from', $from);
        $sql->bindParam(':to', $to);
        $sql->execute();





        if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
            echo'
            <table class="table-bordered" width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="10%"><input type="hidden" name="selectall" value="Select-All">All</th>
                    <th width="3%">id</th>
                    <th width="15%">Date</th>
                    <th width="25%">Supervisor</th>
                    <th width="30%">Task Name</th>
                    <th width="10%">Status</th>
                    <th colspan="2" width="7%">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';

            $i=0;

            while($row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $status=$row['report_status'];

                if($status=="Pending"){
                    $color="color:blue";
                } else {
                    $color="color:green";
                }

                $report_id=$row["report_id"];

                echo'
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$report_id.'"></td>
                    <td>'.$report_id.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['report_date'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["fullname"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row["task_name"].'</td>
                    <td align="center" style='.$color.'><strong>'.$status.'</strong></td>

                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="view_task/view_task.php" method="post" target="_blank">
                            <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="'.$report_id.'">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">View</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>

                    <td align="center">
                        <form action="remove2.php" method="post" onsubmit="return confirm(\'Do you want to remove this reports?\')">
                            <input type="hidden" name="from" value="'.$from.'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="to" value="'.$to.'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="team" value="'.$team.'">
                            <input type="hidden" name="report_id" value="'.$report_id.'">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn-danger">Remove</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>';

                $i++;
            }

            echo '
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action="delete_selected.php" method="post">
                        <input type='hidden' name='ids[]' />
                        <input type='button' name='sub-delete' value='DELETE' />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }
?>
<script>
    let ids=document.querySelector('input[type="hidden"][name="ids[]"]');
    let tmp=[];

    document.querySelector('[name="selectall"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
        let col=document.querySelectorAll('[name="check[]"]');
        col.forEach(chk=>{
            chk.checked=this.checked;
            if( this.checked )tmp.push(chk.value)
            else tmp.splice(tmp.indexOf(chk.value),1)
        });
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('[name="check[]"]').forEach( chk=>{
        chk.addEventListener('change',function(e){
            if( this.checked )tmp.push(this.value)
            else tmp.splice( tmp.indexOf(this.value),1);
        });
    });

    document.querySelector('[name="sub-delete"]').addEventListener('click',function(e){
        ids.value=tmp.join(',')
        this.parentNode.submit()
    });
</script>
```

and

**delete_selected.php**

```
<?php

    include("../../../config/configPDO.php");
    include("../../../config/check.php");


    $checkbox=explode( ',', $_POST['ids'][0] );

    for($i=0;$i < count($checkbox); $i++){
        $report_id=$checkbox[$i];

        $sql="UPDATE ot_report SET status='no' WHERE report_id=:report_id";
        $query=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));

        header("Location: dashboard_engineer.php");

    }

?>
```

Comment: Which part do you not understand - the PHP that creates the pseuo sql, the php that generates the initial page or the javascript?

Comment: @javascript, mktime??

Comment: Ignore the php that generates the page ( especially `mktime` ) as that was only to help produce a `realistic` example. The important thing there is the `checkbox` with the name `check[]` ~ it is NOT within a form at that point ( which is how your code is ) so will NOT appear in the POST array. The javascript is used to keep a record of any checkbox that is checked and will also submit the form. The form submission has all the checkbox values ( ids ) populated at this stage and thus the values held in `ids[]` field are available to process in PHP

Comment: try making a copy of the above, saving to your server and running - that might help understand what I said

Comment: Already use your code. But the select all check box, you remove it. I also want to use the check box to check all box

Comment: The `select-all` checkbox is there and, courtesy of the javascript, does `select all` other checkboxes. If you found this useful and `"already use my (your) code"` perhaps you ought to upvote?!